# JavaScript вычисление индикатора DMI, в чем ошибка

Tags: javascript

Написал индикатор DMI по инструкции [отсюда](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Directional_Movement_(DMI)#CALCULATION)

Сам индикатор:

```
var DMI = function(period){
    this.period = period||14;
    this.upm = [];
    this.dwm = [];
    this.lastquote = null;
    this.PDI = [];
    this.MDI = [];
    this.EMA = new EMA(this.period);
    this.ATR = [];
}

DMI.prototype = {
    reset: function(){
        this.upm = [];
        this.dwm = [];
        this.lastquote = null;
        this.PDI = [];
        this.MDI = [];
        this.EMA = new EMA(this.period);
        this.TR = [];
        this.ATR = [];
    },
    append: function(quote){//Добавление очередной котировки с последующими вычислениями
        if (this.lastquote){
            var um = quote.high - this.lastquote.high; 
            var dm = this.lastquote.low - quote.low;

            //Вычисление истинного диапазона и среднего истинного диапазона ([url]http://berg.com.ua/indicators-overlays/atr/[/url])
            this.TR.push(Math.max((quote.high - quote.low),(quote.high - this.lastquote.close),(this.lastquote.close - quote.low)));
            if (this.TR.length >= this.period){
                if (this.ATR.length == 0){
                    this.ATR.push(this.EMA.average(this.TR))
                }else{
                    this.ATR.push((this.ATR[this.ATR.length - 1]*(this.period - 1) + this.TR[this.TR.length - 1])/this.period)
                }
            }


            //Вычисление +DI (PDI) и -DI (MDI)
            if (um > dm && um > 0){
                this.upm.push(um);
            }else{
                this.upm.push(0);
            }
            if (dm > um && dm > 0){
                this.dwm.push(dm);
            }else{
                this.dwm.push(0);
            }
            if (this.upm.length >= this.period){
                this.PDI.push(100*this.EMA.getFromPrices(this.upm)[this.upm.length - this.period]/this.ATR[this.ATR.length - 1]);
                this.MDI.push(100*this.EMA.getFromPrices(this.dwm)[this.dwm.length - this.period]/this.ATR[this.ATR.length - 1]);
            }


            // Вычисление ADX
            var vals = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.PDI.length; i++){
                vals.push(100*Math.abs(this.PDI[i]-this.MDI[i])/(this.PDI[i]+this.MDI[i]))
            }
            var ADX = null;
            if (vals.length >= this.period){
                ADX = this.EMA.getFromPrices(vals)[vals.length - this.period];
            }
            this.lastquote = quote;
            return {"PDI":this.PDI[this.PDI.length - 1]||null, "MDI":this.MDI[this.MDI.length - 1]||null, "ADX":ADX};
        }else{
            this.lastquote = quote;
            return null;
        }
    }, 



    // Вывод значений индикатора на конкретных котировках
    getFromQuotes: function(quotes,outtype){
        var DMI = [];
        this.reset();
        for (var i = 0; i<quotes.length; i++){
            var tmp = (this.append(quotes[i]));
            if (tmp){
                DMI.push(tmp);
            }
        }
        if (outtype){
            return DMI;
        }else{
            var PDI = [];
            var MDI = [];
            var ADX = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < DMI.length; i++){
                PDI.push(DMI[i].PDI);
                MDI.push(DMI[i].MDI);
                ADX.push(DMI[i].ADX);
            }
            return {"PDI":PDI, "MDI":MDI, "ADX":ADX};
        }
    } 
}
```

Вспомогательный индикатор EMA:

```
var EMA = function (period) {
    this.period = period || 10;
}

EMA.prototype = {
    getFromDeltas: function (deltas, initialprice) {
        if (deltas.length <= this.period) {
            throw ReferenceError('The number of deltas is not enough for such a period: ' + this.period.toString())
        }
        var price = initialprice || 0;
        var prices = [price];
        for (var i = 0; i < deltas.length; i++) {
            price += deltas[i].value || deltas[i];
            prices.push(price);
        }
        return this.getFromPrices(prices);
    },
    getFromQuotes: function (quotes) {
        if (quotes.length <= this.period) {
            throw ReferenceError('The number of quotes is not enough for such a period: ' + this.period.toString())
        }
        var initialprice = quotes[0].open;
        var deltas = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length - 1; i++) {
            deltas.push(quotes[i + 1].open - quotes[i].open);
        }
        deltas.push(quotes[quotes.length - 1].close - quotes[quotes.length - 1].open);
        return this.getFromDeltas(deltas, initialprice);
    },
    getFromPrices: function (prices) {
        if (prices.length < this.period) {
            throw ReferenceError('The number of prices is not enough for such a period: ' + this.period.toString())
        }
        var a = 2 / (this.period + 1);
        var EMA = [this.average(prices.slice(0, this.period))];
        for (var i = this.period; i < prices.length; i++) {
            EMA.push(a * (prices[i] - EMA[i - this.period]) + EMA[i - this.period]);
        }
        return EMA;
    },
    average: function (a) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        return sum / a.length
    }
}
```

После вычислений на различных котировках значения не совпадают с реальными (которые на торговых платформах)

Пробежался с отладчиком, и все равно ошибок не нашел

Котировки использую в виде

```
[{
    "open": 1.14178,
    "high": 1.14203,
    "low": 1.141695,
    "close": 1.14203,
    "created_at": "2018-10-27T00:00:00.000000Z"
}, {
    "open": 1.14203,
    "high": 1.142045,
    "low": 1.14189,
    "close": 1.141915,
    "created_at": "2018-10-27T00:01:00.000000Z"
}
//, и так далее, по возрастанию времени

]
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совпадало, потому что на торговых платформах для вычисления вспомогательных EMA сглаживающие коэффициенты брали, как `1/period`, а я не менял и оставлял, как `2/(period + 1)`